# Archivo de excel se daña al enviarlo por correo desde Apps Script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa en Google Apps Script para convertir un hoja de cálculo de Google Sheets en un archivo de excel y enviarlo por gmail. Ya logré convertirlo y enviarlo como archivo adjunto en el correo; sin embargo, al momento de descargar el archivo y abrirlo en cualquier versión de escritorio de Ms Excel, me sale un error que dice que la extensión del archivo está dañana y no puede ser leída.

Comparto el bloque de código donde envío el correo con el archivo adjunto para ver si alguien me puede colaborar indicándome que estoy haciendo mal, por favor.

```
function enviarInventario(excel, nombreExcel){

  const emailDestinatarios = 'correoDestinatario@gamil.com';

  MailApp.sendEmail({

    to: emailDestinatarios,
    subject: 'Inventario adjunto prueba',
    attachments:{

      fileName: nombreExcel + '.xlsx',
      content: excel.getBytes(),
      mimeType: 'application/xlsx'
    }
  })
}
```

Nota: Para el parámetro denominado 'excel' que recibe la función, le estoy enviando un archivo tipo Blob creado a partir del spreadsheet.

De antemano, muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola espero te sirva este codigo.

```
function enviarCorreo() {
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
var nombrexlsx = "nombre de como se llmara tu excel de desactga.xlsx";
var ssID = "1MCwTLgVyYElskf61iNLn-CdiZbQCQhSAsOadlvB2Drc"; //la ruta de tu Spresdsheet


var emailTo ="email a enviar, si es una cadena concatena una coma (entre comillada)entre correo y correo ";
var emailSubject ="asunto del correo";
var emailText ="cuerpo del correo ";
var AdjuntoExcel = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ssID + "&exportFormat=xlsx", //todo esto dejalo tal cual, es para simular la descarga
    { 
      headers : {Authorization : "Bearer "+ token}
    }
  )
  .getBlob()
  .setName(nombrexlsx);                                 
var OpcionesAvanzadas = { name: emailSubject, htmlBody: emailText , attachments: [AdjuntoExcel]};
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, emailSubject, OpcionesAvanzadas);}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Publico como respuesta ya que no tengo la reputación suficiente para comentar.

Una posible razón  puede ser que la version de MS office que usas no sea compatible con la extension del archivo  (lo dudo)  .Ya que no hay errores en tu código y suponiendo que la forma en que se crea el blob funciona correctamente.

Una posible solución (si tu hoja no tiene formatos) puede ser enviarlo como archivo *CSV*  en lugar de la extension de *XLSX*.

```
 fileName: nombreExcel + '.csv',
  content: excel.getBytes(),
  mimeType: 'text/csv'
```